# iPhone Facebook like without login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I'm am trying to "like" a game app from within a native iOS game (this will give you virtual currency). I have tried a number of approaches, but can't find one that works with a good UX.

The user has already granted my app Facebook publish permissions and I can get an authenticated session fine using the Facebook iOS SDK without making the user login. However when I try to like the app via Open Graph I get this error:
"(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.". Which reading the manual seems about right. It looks like you can't like pages.

So I tried using a (JavaScript) social plugin "like box" embedded in a UIWebView. However this looks ugly and forces the user to login even if my app already has an active Facebook session. I can't find a way to pass my oauth token from my active session to a web view within my app - it might be that the "like box" and JavaScript SDK always force a user to re-authenticate.

So here's my question:

Can anyone describe a way to like a Facebook app/page from within an iOS app without forcing the user to login again and (preferably) without using a social plugin? Or if using a social plugin, how to pass an active Facebook session to the webview that the plugin is embedded in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you giving the same reward to users who already liked before? (Otherwise, that would violate Platform Policies.)

Comment: No - the user can only like the app once - actually 0 times at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem in different case. I have solved this issue this link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_twitter_facebook.htm

In this link provide you to how to configure facebook and twitter within your and If you have once Logged In than don't need to login once again..!!!

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm afraid your tutorial describes the trivial case of making a facebook post using the iOS social framework. It is not possible to "like" via the social framework.

Comment: WelCome!! Not an issue..!! :)